# How to iterate over Max Values for Fuzz Ratio and export to new CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to write some code that will take two lists of names from two csv files, and use the `fuzzywuzzy` library to find the most similar comparisons and export those to a third csv file.

Two problems with my code:

- Firstly, it is not optimizing, just exporting all the ratios I am calculating.
- Secondly, it is all exporting to a single column rather than sticking all values in their own relevant columns i.e. CSV1, CSV2, Fuzz Ratio

  ```
  from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
  import csv

  with open('Documents/test_CSV_1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('Documents/test_CSV_2.csv', 'r') as t2:
      fileone = t1.readlines()
      filetwo = t2.readlines()

  with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
      for i in fileone:
          for j in filetwo:
              outFile.write(i + j+ str(fuzz.ratio(i,j)) + ", " + "\n")
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

Import Packages

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
```

Read the two csv files:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(''Documents/test_CSV_1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Documents/test_CSV_2.csv')
```

Make a empty list

```
matched_names = []
```

Write a Fuzzywuzzy matching code

```
for row1 in df1.index:
    name1 = df1.get_value(row1,"Name1") #Name1 is the column name of df1 of an entity to be matched
    for row2 in df2.index:
        name2= df2.get_value(row2,"Name2")  #Name2 is the column name of df2 of entity to be matched
        matched_token=fuzz.partial_ratio(name1,name2)
        if matched_token> 80: #This is the threshold, you can change according to your neds
            matched_names.append([name1,name2,matched_token])
```

Write the list to df and csv:

```
df_partial_ratio = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name1', 'name2','matched_token'], data=matched_names)
df_partial_ratio.to_csv("Output.csv",  encoding='utf-8')
```

Alternately you can also use below functions like `fuzz.ratio` and `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` according to your data and needs. These functions can be used by just changing a line in the code like below:

```
matched_token=fuzz.ratio(name1,name2)
matched_token=fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name1,name2)
```